# Plugin in Devtools (inspect-element) that shows filename

Tags: debugging, pug, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on an application that has views rendered in the body of other views. The original view files are written in jade, but are obviously converted to HTML before being rendered. Is there a way to look up the original jade filename and/or filepath in devtools/inspect-element with or without an external browser plugin? I'm using Chrome for this but would consider another browser if it has the functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get away with just including comments that state where the source of the view is, such as including a `// someFile.jade` at the start of that jade file with perhaps a `// End of someFile.jade` at the end. You can also probably include a conditional so that that only displays when in a debugging mode if it's bothersome. Such as:

```
//- someFile.jade
include globals.jade //- Allows for checking if in debugging mode
if debuggingMode:
  // someFile.jade
...
if debuggingMode:
  // End of someFile.jade
```

I'm thinking you'd need a build tool to create a map from the HTML to the Jade files (ie: filename.html.map). Although, I've seen them used with CSS and JavaScript files, but don't recall seeing any for HTML. I would probably also interested in something like that. However, I gave this answer in the off chance it doesn't exist, yet. However, the above should do the job in any case.

Comment: Normally, that would work well. But I didn't write most of the codebase on which I'm working and there are way too many views to do that retroactively.